# scheduled and customized git add, commit, push cron job

Tags: git, cron

for example, current directory we have 01~10 folders
01 02 03 04 ... 10

Currently, we add each folder (01, 02) by hands and push it to github so that the students can take a programming quiz. (each folder has one daily quz set).

I would like to stage each folder every day and commit, push it to github. 
Can I automate this? I would not mind typing script so that it runs with customzed schedule (9am in the morning every day)

I first attempted using AWS lambda but quickly realized I will need some kind of cloud storage where git runs (e.g. EC2)

Any rough suggestion how to approach this problem? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running a Unix based system you could have a cronjob that runs a shell script every weekday at 9am.

```
0 9 * * 1-5 sh <full-path-to-script>
```

In the shell script you should:

1. cd into your git repo
2. get all the untracked folders
3. sort the list of folders
4. commit/push the first entry of the list

Comment: appreciate it, I will go try your suggestion!